# Radio buttons - decimal place option

Tags: java, android, radio-button

I'm making a program that does certain types of math for you. The user inputs a number and hits a button that brings them to another activity and and displays the answer plus the formula and more.. But sometimes the answer has a decimal with a crazy amount of numbers after the decimal.

Now, I already know how to change the amount of numbers after the decimal, but i want to give the option to the user on how many digits they want after the decimal using radio buttons on the same page with the editText.

How would i do that?

this is what i have so far....

input page w/ radiobuttons-

public void click (View view){

```
    boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

    switch (view.getId()){
        case R.id.radioButton1:
            if (checked){
                Intent check = new Intent(this, Output.class);
                String value = "0.0";
                check.putExtra("PATTERN", value);
            }
        break;
        case R.id.radioButton2:
            if (checked){
                Intent check = new Intent(this, Output.class);
                String value = "0.00";
                check.putExtra("PATTERN", value);
            }
            break;
        case R.id.radioButton3:
            if (checked){
                Intent check = new Intent(this, Output.class);
                String value = "0.000";
                check.putExtra("PATTERN", value);
            }
            break;
        case R.id.radioButton4:
            if (checked){
                Intent check = new Intent(this, Output.class);
                String value = "0.000000000";
                check.putExtra("PATTERN", value);
            }
            break;
    }

}
```

output page-

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String pattern = intent.getStringExtra("PATTERN");
String answerS = intent.getStringExtra("MESSAGE");

double fix = Double.parseDouble(answerS);
DecimalFormat dFormatter = new DecimalFormat(pattern);
String answerSS = "" + dFormatter.format(fix);

TextView answer = findViewById(R.id.answer);
answer.setText(answerSS);
```

[this is the layout and what options i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUjSl.png)

Comment: Show us some code. This is an awesome question but there is no way we can help you without first seeing what you've done already.

Comment: Also elaborate on your design a bit. What should your radio-buttons actually stand for? Number of decimal places? Like "all of them", "only 5", "none"?

Comment: but you send pattern in string as intent .

Comment: i test this way and i get value just example like  double fix=256.332165;
        DecimalFormat dFormatter = new DecimalFormat("#."+"00");
        String answerSS = "" + dFormatter.format(fix);
        Log.d("answer",answerSS);

Comment: and getting value like  D/answer: 256.33

Answer (score 0):

Use a [DecimalFormatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html)
depending on each RadioButton:

```
double number = 3.14159265359;
DecimalFormat numberFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.0000");
System.out.println(numberFormat.format(number));
```

Will output: *3.1415*.

You can expand it by using more or less *0* or use # after the delimiter aswell like:

```
double number = 3.1500000000;
DecimalFormat numberFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.####");
System.out.println(numberFormat.format(number));
```

Leaving you with the output *3.15*.

Comment: thats what i did but im not sure how to implement that into the radio buttons

Comment: Do a switch-case to check which radiobutton is active. For example when outputting the number to console or GUI-Element.

Answer (score 0):

change this thing..

```
switch (view.getId()){
    case R.id.radioButton1:
        if (checked){
            Intent check = new Intent(this, Output.class);
            String value = "0";
            check.putExtra("PATTERN", value);
        }
    break;
    case R.id.radioButton2:
        if (checked){
            Intent check = new Intent(this, Output.class);
            String value = "00";
            check.putExtra("PATTERN", value);
        }
        break;
    case R.id.radioButton3:
        if (checked){
            Intent check = new Intent(this, Output.class);
            String value = "000";
            check.putExtra("PATTERN", value);
        }
        break;
    case R.id.radioButton4:
        if (checked){
            Intent check = new Intent(this, Output.class);
            String value = "000000000";
            check.putExtra("PATTERN", value);
        }
        break;
}





    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String pattern = intent.getStringExtra("PATTERN");
    String answerS = intent.getStringExtra("MESSAGE");

    double fix = Double.parseDouble(answerS);
    DecimalFormat dFormatter = new DecimalFormat("#."+pattern);
    String answerSS = "" + dFormatter.format(fix);

    TextView answer = findViewById(R.id.answer);
    answer.setText(answerSS);
```

Comment: okay, that at least made it run. but now i have null after the decimal instead of what i clicked, even if i dont click anything

Comment: if you don't click redio button then pattern not getting any things it null value then set nothing. you set pattern if radio button not selected.

Comment: done.. still says null. i dont think the pattern is being received by the radio buttons...